# heroku syncdb for existing Django project with multiple apps

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am deploying an existing Django project (with multiple apps) to Heroku. I have followed the steps in the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django). When I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

```
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... failed
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

I tried these suggestions, but the problem persists. Also, I wonder if there's a way to automatically create the database tables for all my existing apps without having to specify each one.

I am also using South, and I am still not sure how to properly transfer my migrations to Heroku. Perhaps that is part of the problem?

Comment: Are you in the main directory of your project? Are you able to run "git push heroku master" successfully?

Comment: I am. However, I have been working on a secondary branch (so I don't screw things up too significantly). I have been pushing using `git push heroku secondary_brach_name:master`.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:{YOUR_APP_NAME}.git
git config heroku.remote heroku
```

The `app` being referred to here is not your django app, but your project name.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. That remote already exists for me.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 git remote?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem, though I'm a bit confused as to why it worked. Instead of running the commands from my project directory (where my manage.py resides), I had to go up one directory and do `heroku run python my_django_project_name/manage.py syncdb`